# My bike is dying on random

Tags: electrical, carburetor

Okay so I’ve had this bike (2004 gs500) for roughly two weeks and it’s ran perfect. Today I was riding with perfect preformence when I throttled and noticed it waited a second before doing anything ( I was still moving at this point)then it started doing just fine and when I pulled in the driveway it did the same thing and when I was taking off it died. It would crank and crank without trying to hit a lick. I have it roughly 30 seconds and it cranked up like a new one and ran fine up the driveway. When I left the house about a mile later it did the same thing after i got it started again I drove it around with no issues

Comment: Check the fuel supply system for an intermittant blickage.

Comment: Check the fuel cap vent for blockage.  If you try to open the fuel cap when this happens see if there is a vacuum in the tank.